# call script from django unittest

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I'm trying to run a script from a django unit test but failing to do so.

The script I want to call can be run from the command line with `python -m webapp.lib.cron.my_cron`

I've tried:

```
from subprocess import call
call("python -m webapp.lib.cron.my_cron")
```

and receive the following error:

> **FileNotFoundError:** [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python -m webapp.lib.cron.my_cron'

How can I run this script in a django unittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the arguments as a list, not a string.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python",  "-m", "webapp.lib.cron.my_cron"])
```

Answer (score 0):

use Popen because subprocess.Popen is more general than subprocess.call.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["python",  "-m", "webapp.lib.cron.my_cron"])
```